# How to pass argument in bash pipe from terminal

Tags: bash

i have a bash script show below in a file called test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $1
echo "execution done"
```

when i execute this script using

**Case-1**

```
./test.sh "started"

    started
    execution done
```

showing properly

**Case-2**

If i execute with

```
bash test.sh "started"
```

i'm getting the out put as

started

execution done

But i would like to execute this using a cat or wget command with **arguments**
For example like.

**Q1**

cat test.sh |bash

Or using a command

**Q2**

wget -qO - "url contain bash" |bash

So in Q1 and Q2 how do i pass argument

Something simlar to this shown in this github

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Please refer installation script

Comment: Please let us know the reason behind why you want to use `wget` or `cat` when you have a working script with you?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i will be keeping the script in github. And user can just say wget -qO- <url> |bash to execute in system. They don't need to download then change the file permission etc.

Comment: Look at how **GNU Parallel** does it under *"Prerequisites"* https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Prerequisites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ bash <(curl -Ls url_contains_bash_script) arg1 arg2
```

---

Explanation:

```
$ echo -e 'echo "$1"\necho "done"' >test.sh
$ cat test.sh
echo "$1"
echo "done"
$ bash <(cat test.sh) "hello"
hello
done
$ bash <(echo -e 'echo "$1"\necho "done"') "hello"
hello
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pipe to bash; bash runs as standard in your terminal.

If I have a script and I have to use cat, this is what I'll do:

```
cat script.sh > file.sh; chmod 755 file.sh; ./file.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

`script.sh` is the source script. You can replace that call with anything you want.

This has security implications though; just running an arbitrary code in your shell - especially with wget where the code comes from a remote location.

Comment: Thank you. But my file is not in local machine.. It is in github. How do i do at that time. Do i need to save it in temp. Is there any other way??

Comment: GitHub supports raw formats. There is a `raw` button next to each file in a repo, use that to get the url, which you can then arg to `curl`. E.g. this is the URL of John Papa's angular styleguide readme: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/master/README.md. Use it as argument to curl and the raw readme content will output in your shell.

Comment: So i need to download it and run it. is it possible to  push the raw to stdout and execute with arguments??

Comment: @Vipin The raw is printing to stdout already. Do you mean copy/paste into your shell? Yes, it'll run line by line. Just exclude the first line which has the directive.

Comment: Ok. For example in my question test.sh is located at githhub, i will download it is using wget -qO - <<raw file url>>. Then on the same command i'm pipe it with bash. So that it will execute the pushed file. In my case my  test.sh contain an argument which need to be passed from commandline. So when i execute wget -qO - <<githib rawurl>> |bash . How to do that??

Comment: One way for that is to just add the arguments after `file.sh` above.

Comment: Can you please provide me an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163577/discussion-between-cst1992-and-vipin).